# Smart pointers messed with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, copy-constructor, initializer-list

I'm trying to run a simple piece of code with shared pointers.

```
//in the class definition
Rule(std::string name, 
     std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RuleMember>>> rules);
...

//in function 'main'
shared_ptr<Rule> expression(new Rule("expression", {
    { identifier },
    { expression, add, identifier }
}));
```

Compilation is successful, but "The program stops working" when I try to run it. I stepped through the code and it fails when execution leaves `main` (which is the function containing this code).

Interesting is that when I explicitly add a constructor around the expression, it works:

```
shared_ptr<Rule> expression(new Rule("expression", {
    { identifier },
    { shared_ptr<Rule> (expression), add, identifier }
}));
```

I've got three questions:

1. What happens when I pass a local `shared_ptr` variable (`expression` in this case) to an initializer list? I thought that a copy constructor would be called, creating a new `shared_ptr` for the collection I initialized.
2. Is it possible that this `shared_ptr` in the collection that is pointed to by `expression` in function scope wouldn't contain a valid pointer just because the constructor of `expression` hasn't finished yet?
3. Does the fact that program stops working at `{ __atomic_fetch_add(__mem, __val, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL); }` somewhere in `<atomicity.h>` has something to do with this, or is it just a random place?

Comment: Regarding (1), as you're in-process of constructing the very object of you're desire to copy, I don't see how that is going to happen. And your surmise of (2) being a direct result of the failure of (1) (at least as I read your code) would seem reasonable. Fyi, clang will exhibit a warning (*"variable `expression` is uninitialized when used within its own initialization"*) for the first example. I would be hard-pressed to describe it any better than that.

Comment: @WhozCraig, then it means I must initialize the Rule object after smart pointer is created. I thought I would spare some lines. Thanks.

Comment: @firda, I belive I'm not creating two distict shared_ptrs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr (9)

Comment: Careful. If I understand your usage pattern here (pretty big "if") you may well create a circular self-referencing shared pointer (it references itself via its own rule vector). You may want to consider how a weak-pointer may be a better fit somewhere in here (note: i've not really thought about it beyond the potential problem of a self-referencing shared-pointer). Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you, I'll think about it. Maybe you could write your comments into an aswer..

Comment: I'm actually interested in someone else proffering up other tidbits. You never know, We may have missed something obvious that neither of us thought about. Wouldn't be the first time. Always good to get multiple views on something (thus my +1 for the question). I'll keep a watch on it though, and post something later if no one else does (or you could always post your own answer if you feel comfortable with understanding the dilemma; SO certainly supports self-directed answers).

Comment: @user35443: I have deleted my comment almost immediately (when realized I was wrong) and went testing... results in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is not initialized when used inside the initializer list. Look what happens:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

struct Rule {
    string name;
    vector<vector<shared_ptr<Rule>>> rules;
    Rule(string name,
      vector<vector<shared_ptr<Rule>>> rules)
    : name(name), rules(rules) {}
};

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Rule> identifier, add;
    shared_ptr<Rule> expression(new Rule("expression", {
        { identifier },
        { expression, add, identifier }
    }));

    cout << expression->name << ": "
        << (uintptr_t)expression.get() << " ? "
        << (uintptr_t)expression->rules[1][0].get();
}
```

Output:

```
expression: 536937312 ? 2282820
```

It crashes when I try to acces `expression->rules[1][0]->name`;

Comment: surprised I got no warning (g++ -Wall -pedantic)

Comment: clang is better: `warning: variable 'expression' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]` - `{ expression, add, identifier }`

Comment: Could this be reported as a bug (or missing warning)?

Comment: @user35443: Maybe, used Cygwin GCC 4.8.3 32bit